# Exercise about power set and orders relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I can't really figure it out how to solve the following exercise:

Let $X$ be a set and $Y$ a subset of $X$ containing at least two distinct elements. Let's consider the partially ordered set $2^X$ ordered by inclusion and define $B=\{\{y\}\space y\in Y\}$ and $Z$ being a fixed subset of $2^X$, prove:

1) $Z$ is a majorant of $B$ iff $Y$ is contained in $Z$,

2) $Z$ is a minor ant of $B$ iff $Z$ is the empty set,

3) what are (if they exist) $\sup B$ and $\inf B$.

I can't figure what exactly the exercise is asking to me so I'd like a step by step solution.

Comment: Do you understand what all of the terms mean (beyond just knowing the definition)?

Comment: @DanielFischer actually yes, however I'm at my first course on set theory so I'm not very familiar with this kind of exercise

Comment: Okay. Then you should be able to do it by just specialising the general definitions to the case at hand. In a partially ordered set, what is the definition of an element $x$ being a majorant of a subset $A$?